# Change values from a tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensor

I'm learning RL with tensor flow and `tf_agents` and right now i'm working with the cart-pole env from `suite_gym` in a `tf_py_environment`.

I have this initial time step that i got from `time_step = eval_env.reset()`:

```
    TimeStep(step_type=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0], dtype=int32)>, reward=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>, discount=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.], dtype=float32)>, observation=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.01901868, -0.01773789,  0.03148418, -0.01060838]],
      dtype=float32)>)
```

And i would like to change the initial values of the numpy array of the observation `tf.Tensor`, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of the observation Tensor you can just act directly on the Tensor through any normal TF function that acts on it (there are many mathematical operations to do so).

I should warn you however that the TimeStep is just an output of the environment. It is **not** the environment state, but just a representation of it. Therefore changing it will not resulting in changes to the environment. It's a bit like me sending you a postcard and telling you that I am in India, and then you crossing the word India and changing it with Brazil; the postcard is changed, but I'm still in India.

To change the actual environment state you have to act directly on the environment object, but that is typically not recommended unless the environment already supports some method to import a user-defined state.